# Calculating checksum in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, hana

I have a query in `SAP HANA` like below. I am calculating `check_sum` based on some column in the table

```
select Name, address, salary, phone_number, department, HASH_SHA256( TO_BINARY(COALESCE(Name, 'ABC')), TO_BINARY(COALESCE(address, 'ABC')), TO_BINARY(COALESCE(salary, 0)), TO_BINARY(COALESCE(department, 'ABC'))) as check_sum from table1;
```

Now I have created the same table in `Big Query`.

I want to calculate `check_sum` in `Big Query` and get the same result as in `SAP HANA`

I have tried like below

```
select Name, address, salary, phone_number, department, TO_HEX(SHA256((TO_BINARY(COALESCE(Name, 'ABC')), TO_BINARY(COALESCE(address, 'ABC')), TO_BINARY(COALESCE(salary, 0)), TO_BINARY(COALESCE(department, 'ABC')))) as check_sum from table1;
```

It says `TO_BINARY` function is not available.

I tried to convert the column to `BYTES` but it says `NUMERIC` cannot be converted to `BYTES`

```
select Name, address, salary, phone_number, department, TO_HEX(SHA256(CAST(COALESCE(Name, 'ABC') AS BYTES), CAST(COALESCE(address, 'ABC') AS BYTES), CAST(COALESCE(salary, 0) AS BYTES), CAST(COALESCE(department, 'ABC') AS BYTES))) as check_sum from table1;
```

But it is still not working. What is the correct way to match the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below this should give you correct values

```
select Name, address, salary, phone_number, department, UPPER(TO_HEX(SHA256(CONCAT(CAST(COALESCE(Name, 'ABC') AS STRING), CAST(COALESCE(address, 'ABC') AS STRING), CAST(COALESCE(salary, 0) AS STRING), CAST(COALESCE(department, 'ABC') AS STRING))))) as check_sum from table1;
```